# React-Native Video autoplay code not working

Tags: react-native

My requirement is when the page loads the video should be start playing from the local storage and but it doesnt play at all.
Initially the state **paused:true** , and when the video loads i tried to change the state to false , but the video doesnt play automatically.

```
<Video
  onEnd={this.handleEnd}
  onLoad={this.handleLoad}
  onProgress={this.handleProgress}
  autoplay={true}
  paused={this.state.paused}
  ref={ref=> {
    this.player = ref;
  }}
  resizeMode="cover"
  source={{uri:this.state.v_url}}
  volume={this.state.muted==true?0.0:1.0}
  muted={this.state.muted}
/>

handleLoad = (meta) => {
  console.log('Its working',this.props)
  this.setState({
  duration:meta.duration,
  paused:false,
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use @coffeebeanslabs/react-native-inviewport to detect whether your  component is in your device viewport:

Install using: `npm i @coffeebeanslabs/react-native-inviewport`

then do the following in your code:

```
import InViewPort from "@coffeebeanslabs/react-native-inviewport";

checkVideoVisible(isVideoVisible) { 
    this.setState({videoVisible: isVideoVisible});
}

<InViewPort onChange={(isVideoVisible) => this.checkVideoVisible(isVideoVisible)}>
    <Video
        paused={!this.state.videoVisible} 
    />
</InViewPort>
```

Comment: This isnt properly working on ios ...